# i have a speed issue when press replay button

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

```
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, hi);
function hi (event:Event){
    if(player.hitTestObject(object)){
       gotoAndStop(25);
       }
}
```

when i press on the replay button the speed keeps getting bigger each time, do u guys know why? ;(

if i have this

```
player.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveChar);
function moveChar(event:Event):void{
```

that will be a problem cause im repeating FRAME event? or it's okay cause one is for replay and another is for move the character

Comment: Maybe you need to denounce the button...

Answer (score 0):

I'd avoid using more than one ENTER_FRAME event - I think that's called 'multi-threaded' and Flash can have a hard time figuring out what happens when. Better to have ONE ENTER_FRAME listener and have all of your game action triggered from the handler it points to.
That said, you MIGHT be getting an increase in speed if, when the game restarts, you add the ENTER_FRAME listener again. If so your game will be triggering the handler twice per frame. You'll need to remove the event listener each time the game ends, before it restarts.